# Is this a cheap Chinese fuse or a current shunt?

Tags: multimeter, fuses

I got this cheap DT-830B multimeter as a bonus when ordering stuff from a Chinese internet shop.

I opened it up and was wondering if this is a fuse or a current shunt?
Since the multimeter works out of the box I assumed there must be a fuse in it, as I did not expect it to function without a fuse, but that weird thing is all I can find on either side of the PCB, it has two white lines under it. Also there seems to be contacts on the side of the PCB that I usually associate with a fuse.

Help a confused soul!

[image: PCB]

Comment: That "fuse" looks like the actual current shunt resistor.

Comment: That "Fuse ?" **is** the current shunt. This multimeter, as all cheap multimeters, **does not have a fuse** !!! The two contacts marked "What ?" might be the battery contacts, test contacts or they don't serve any purpose. If you want to learn how a **proper** DMM is constructed, watch the relevant EEVBlog videos, example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsTZuPN7wQQ This meter is more an example of how to build something **CHEAP**.

Answer (score 3):

As @FakeMoustache says, the part you have indicated with "fuse?" is a current shunt.

To be exact, it is the shunt for the 10A current range of the meter.  R13 (just above the large shunt) would appear to be the shunt for lower currents.

The notches in the 10A shunt are from the "fine tuning."  The shunt is made with a resistance that is a little too low.  Then there is a calibration step where bits are shaved off of the shunt until the current measurement is correct.  High current shunts in more expensive meters don't necessarily look any better.

The other two pads you indicated might be for a fuse that isn't installed in this model.  I searched for images of the 830B, and found similar meters with similar pads that were marked "fuse" - but which also did not have a fuse installed.  I expect there's  jumper or trace on the other side of the board that can be removed or cut when a fuse holder (or just a fuse) is installed.